# Flutter - min spacing between Row/Column items

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I try to build layout from picture with no success. How can I do it? (See what I've tried below)

[image: layout description]

I build `Row` like this:

```dart
final row = Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  children: [
    Item(),
    SizedBox(width: _minSpacing),
    Item(),
    SizedBox(width: _minSpacing),
    Item(),
  ],
);
```

Works good, but can't downscale content on overflow. So I put this thing inside `FittedBox` to support downscaling:

```dart
final fittedRow = FittedBox(
  fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
  child: row,
);
```

At this point `Row` stopped to distribute free space between items. It seems `FittedBox` tries to be as small as possible and don't provide free space for `Row`. So I also tried to put it inside `Container` to maybe stretch `FittedBox`:

```dart
Container(
  width: double.infinity,
  child: fittedRow,
);
```

But `Row` still won't spread its children. The best thing I could do, is to set `BoxFit.contain` - then `FittedBox` at least start to upscale `Row` to fill whole screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Flexible Widget and assign them flex value.

```
final row = Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: [
      Flexible(child: Item(),flex: 1,),

      Flexible(child: Item(),flex: 1,),

      Flexible(child: Item(),flex: 1,),
    ],
  );
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! Little note: this solution doesn't require `FittedBox` or `Container` around `Row`. It won't really SCALE items on overflow, but it's not a problem in my case

Comment: Oh, and I also have to put `SizedBox`-es between `Flexible` widgets to create min spacing

Answer (score 1):

If you wrap your items with Flexible widget and assign them flex value i think you will get you want exactly, it will set up your items automatically depend on phone's screen